# why is this do-while calculation is wrong?

Tags: java

When I enter 20 for current5, minuteCurrent should be 240, but do part keeps working even if minuteCurrent is over 240. Why? I tried so many more things, but they didn't help.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class Person {

String name;
int heartRatePer5;
int current5;

void alarm() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        System.out.print("!!! ");
    System.out.println();
}

void stopAlarm() {
    System.out.println("Alarm stopped");
    }
}

public class App{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person1 = new Person();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the current heart rate per 5 seconds: ");
    person1.current5 = input.nextInt();
    int minuteCurrent = person1.current5 * 12;
    // minuteCurrent = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Normalizing.");
        person1.stopAlarm();
        //minuteCurrent = input.nextInt();
        break;
    }

    while (minuteCurrent < 220);

}
```

}

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your `do-while` will always stop on the first run because you have `break` at the end. Did you mean to have an if statement before it?

Comment: Trim your code down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please. The whole "alarm" is not needed.

Comment: does it even work to put the while statement a whole line below the do ??

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Yes. Why wouldn't it?!

Comment: @Biffen sorry for the hyperbolic punctuation.  I've never seen it written like that, and I thought it might trip up the compiler.  It certainly seems like an ugly syntactical decision.  But if it works it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `do` part keeps working even if minuteCurrent is over 240

When you say *keeps* working: I assume you mean: *works **exactly once***.

This is normal; it is a guarantee of `do`. [The statements within the `do` block are always executed at least once](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Perhaps you want a regular `while` loop instead?

The inductive case should look like this:

```
while (minuteCurrent < 220) {
    minuteCurrent = input.nextInt();
}
```

I am unclear what the effect is of `person1.stopAlarm();`, or how many times you want to print the "Normalizing" message. So this may not be a full fix of your algorithm. But I think switching from a `do-while` to a regular `while` loop should fix at least the confusion that you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Do while loops work differently than while loops.

> Notice the while loop condition is now moved to after the do while
>   loop body. The do while loop body is always executed at least once,
>   and is then executed repeatedly while the while loop condition is
>   true.

[See more here.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/while.html)

How can you fix it?  Change your while loop to look like this:

```
while (minuteCurrent < 220) {
            System.out.println("Normalizing.");
            person1.stopAlarm();
            break;
}
```

Also, I have no idea why you are using a while loop.  It would make a lot more sense to just use an if statement - it's the same thing as a while loop with a break at the end.

Comment: I wanted it to keep asking if it is not less than 220. I should be able to do it with if statements, yes. Thank you